# Why did I fail to launch TensorBoard on jupyter notebook?

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I am using tf 2.0 and tensorboard 2.0. I want to use tb in jupyter notebook but get the error:

> ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with -6). Contents of
>   stderr: [libprotobuf ERROR
>   external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:393]
>   Invalid file descriptor data passed to
>   EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add(). [libprotobuf FATAL
>   external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367]
>   CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed:
>   GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):

Comment: how you are doing it, could you share the steps.

Comment: @Zaven Badalyan: Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share the code to reproduce your issue so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the code that reproduces this tensor board issue https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/10_neural_nets_with_keras.ipynb